# Is this SLOPE of the line even possible?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, slope

Is it even possible to build a line having slope of $3$? Could it be a mistake?

[image]

Comment: Slopes run from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ (excluded). What makes you think differently ?

Comment: Looks like there is a direct example of it working, so I'll guess that yes it is possible.

Comment: Of course it is.  Why do you think that a slope of $3$ wouldn't work?

Comment: To be more useful the graph you posted doesn't have the point $(-2,-8)$ plotted it has $(-2,0)$ and $(0,-8)$ plotted. These are different.

Comment: My mistake... I built a line based on the coordinates of a point! I didn't pay attention to the problem description and marked separately point x-coordinate as a point and y-coordinate as a point and then joined them together... sorry!

Comment: I think you graphed a line with slope -4.....

Answer (score 12):

A slope of $3 = \frac{3}{1}$ means that starting at any point on the line (like say $(-2,-8)$), if you move $3$ units **up** and $1$ unit **right** then you'll get another point on the line.

[image]

So, yes.  It is possible.

My advice is to [try playing around with different points and slopes on WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=line+with+slope+3+passing+through+point+(-2,-8)) to get a feel for it.

Answer (score 4):

Not a mistake.  You seem to have a very basic misunderstanding.  The line you drew passes through the TWO points (-2,0) and (0,-8). Its slope is -4. That's
just one problem.

Answer (score 2):

Slope of a line is nothing but the tangent of angle which the line make with $x$-axis or simply speaking $\tan\theta$.

Since value of $\tan\theta$ vary from $\infty$ to $-\infty$ so yes a slope of 3 for a line is possible.

Now, you may have the question that How to construct a line having slope 3? Since you have the point (-2,-8), just plot it on cartesian axes and extend a line from that point such that on moving along line you will move a distance of 3 units on $y$-axis for a distance of 1 unit on $x$-axis.

Comment: then writing the equation in the slope y-intercept form, isn't it supposed to look like this:
y=3/1x-2=0 ?

Comment: Yes @loewitz you can use the slope intercept form. The equation will be same as you stated in the comment. But there the zero is invalid. The equation will be y=3/1x-2

Comment: When writing the equation in the slope y-intercept form I understand I have to write y=... and this is the beginning of the equation, I also understand I need to write 3/1 because that is the fraction representing the slope... I also understand writing the '-2' part because that is where the line is crossing the y-axis... but why do I have to write the 'x' ???

Comment: Whenever you are giving the equation of a line in a plane (in 2-Dimentions) you have to specify or establish a relation between x and y.

Comment: so, I understand that in the left part of such equation I will have to write Y=... and then the right part of the equation has to contain 'X'?

Comment: It doesn't matter what is left part or what is right one.y=3/1x-2 and 3/1x-2=y are the same.

Comment: So, I found this formula for writing an equation of a line in slope intercept form:
==============================
Y=MX+B
==============================
where y is..? a variable?
m is the slope 3/1
x is a variable too
and b is is the y-intercept (i.e. where the drawn line is crossing the y-axis on the graph)?
Please decode these for me!

Comment: Yes,this is absolutely correct. This is the same thing which we call slope intercept form.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of a line with its [general form of equation](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-general-form.html).

$ax + by + c = 0$

Then you can represent a vertical line when $b = 0$
The same goes for horizontal ones when $a = 0$

The only constrains come if $a = 0$ and $b = 0$, then it does not represent a line any more.